# Como validar en un formulario reactivo de angular la entrada de datos para que sean solo numeros?

Tags: regex, angular, validación, entrada

Tengo un formulario reactivo en **Angular 5.2.0**. Configure las validaciones; nid, name, email, address. Todas trabajan bien, muestran el mensaje correcto en cada caso. Pero en el caso de una (N.I.D.), la cual pido acepte solo numeros, el mensaje de error aparece ya sean letras, numeros o caracteres especiales. La he usado sin el compose, esa sola validacion. He cambiado la expresion regular en el pattern varias veces. Hasta he usado el pattern en el input, pero sin exito. Sigue apareciendo el mensaje:
"**Your NID must contain only numbers**"

El html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4">NID</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="nid" #nid pattern="[1-9]\d{6,10}" />
</div>
<div *ngIf="userForm.controls['nid'].invalid && (userForm.controls['nid'].dirty || userForm.controls['nid'].touched)" class="text-light badge-danger my-2 py-2">
    <div *ngFor="let validation of user_validation_messages.nid" >
        <div style="font-size: smaller !important;" *ngIf="userForm.get('nid').hasError(validation.type) && (userForm.get('nid').dirty || userForm.get('nid').touched)">
            {{validation.message}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

El typescript

```
/* Los mensajes */
user_validation_messages = {
    'nid': [
        { type: 'required', message: 'NID is required' },
        { type: 'minlength', message: 'NID must be at least 6 characters long' },
        { type: 'maxlength', message: 'NID cannot be more than 10 characters long' },
        { type: 'pattern', message: 'Your NID must contain only numbers' }
    ],

/* La validacion */
this.userForm = this.fb.group({
     nid: [null, Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(6),
        Validators.maxLength(10),
        Validators.pattern('/^[1-9]\d{6,10}$/')
    ])],
```

**1 Edicion**

Una muestra del resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Veo que la longitud mínima es 6, pero por otro lado la longitud mínima en la expresión regular es 7. Quizás estés probando con un número de 6 cifras y por eso no lo reconoza. Prueba con "1234567", ¿funciona?

Comment: El problema no es la cantidad minima o maxima. Pero al estar dentro del rango, aparece el mensaje de error diciendo que deben ser numeros; escribas letras o numeros siempre aparece el mensaje. Asi sea "1234567"

Comment: Para descartar cualquier problema con la expresión regular, prueba a utilizar `'/.*/'`. Funciona así?

Comment: Pues no. Me lanza el mismo mensaje de error. Elimine el pattern en el input tambien

Comment: No sé si en pattern hay que introducir una expresión regular en formato string o directamente la expresión. Podrías probar con `Validators.pattern(/.*/)` (sin las comillas) a ver si funciona.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, eran las comillas.

Comment: Hola! Puedes comentar como se usa la parte de mensajes personalizados de los errores, me interesa ese punto, gracias!!

Comment: Saludos. Eso fue para un proyecto viejo. Tendría que revisar que actualizaciones hacer hoy en día. Si gustas puedes revisar el código: https://github.com/pulidovpe/mean-library/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas mezclando comillas `'` con delimitadores `/`. O usas comillas o usar delimitadores.

Además, con `[1-9]` no estas tomando en cuenta el `0`.

Una expresión regular más sencilla es `^\d+$`. Con `\d` tomás todos los dígitos, y no tomás las longitudes porque de todos modos ya estás validando el mínimo y el máximo con los otros validadores y te dan los mensajes correspondientes.

Comment: En el caso de [1-9] lo hacia para no permitir que un usuario teclee un NID que empiece por cero. De todas formas, gracias por tu acotacion.

Comment: Tenés razón. Es cierto. Por lo menos espero haberte ayudado a no usar los delimitadores en la expresión porque ya los estas usando en los validadores.

Comment: Claro que si. No sabia que no deben usarse ambos delimitadores. Gracias a ti

Answer (score 0):

Gracias al usuario [Julio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/73513/julio) por ayudarme con sus sugerencias.

En este caso; usando **pattern(/.*/)** sin las comillas han funcionado las demas validaciones y no ha aparecido el mensaje de error. Tanto si tecleo numeros como letras.

He probado la expresion regular apropiada **pattern(/^[1-9]\d{6,10}$/)** tambien sin las comillas y al fin ha funcionado. Parece que ese era todo el problema.

Gracias por la ayuda.